# How do I convert an audio stream to MP3 using Java?

Tags: java, mp3, capture, encode, recording

Is it possible using Java to convert a real time audio stream from the mixer to MP3?

- It has to be converted chunk by chunk otherwise the memory will be exhausted.
- I already know how to record but only to lossless formats such as wav and aiff.
- I need conversion as the audio comes in.

Answer (score 4):

May be you could use [LAMEOnJ](http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj/), which is a 100% Java API wrapping the standard LAME API (LAME being a MP3 encoder).

I am not sure however it would encode "chunk by chunk"...

Comment: It is not pure 100% Java.

Answer (score 2):

Use Xuggler to do it.  It's free, and open source (LGPL), and uses libmp3lame under the covers.  And the [MediaTool API](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction) in Xuggler gives lots of examples of how to use it:

Answer (score 1):

Lame is indeed the de facto standard on MP3 encoding, partly because of its high quality (encoding MP3 is hard to do right... and it is a subjective art), partly because of legal issues (MP3 is a patented technique, AFAIK, that's why you get Lame binaries from a limited number of sites, most of them in countries where these legal issues are less (or not) enforced).

The LAMEOnJ project found by VonC seems to use a non-free JNI implementation, but I suppose you can do your own binding with JNI or even JNA, particularly if you target a precise system.

Answer (score 0):

As to the first question - is it possible, the only limitation I can see would be processor speed. If the algorithm you are using and your processor are both fast enough, there is no reason why it wouldn't be possible.

I know this isn't Java source, but it may get you on the right track - try looking at the [Lame MP3 Encoder](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).

As far as I know all MP3 conversion algorithms work chunk by chunk. They don't need to read the whole WAV file to begin conversion, but they convert on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new process in Java and write the stream to the stdin of to a tool like [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) to have it convert the audio data to MP3 on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

try using Ring buffer to encode the raw audio buffer in fly.