# Need Sample code to capture audio in mp3 format and play it using Java

Tags: java, audio, mp3, capture, replay

I need to capture audio in mp3 format using Java and was looking for any sample code. Any code that converts wave file into mp3 would also work. The code should work on Windows and Mac. I looked at JLayer but could not find any sample code. I used JMF but the CaptureDeviceManager does not find any device.Please let me know the usage code as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343240/how-do-i-convert-an-audio-stream-to-mp3-using-java

Comment: Have you attempted anything so far?  This sounds strangely like an assignment I had in a Python class where we had to play ogg vorbis files

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a real question. You should ask one question at a time, preferably showing some code and your question about it. For example: show some of you code using JMF and ask people how you would get it to detect a device.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't sample code, but there is a library here http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html that works with mp3 format in Java. I hope it can help. I only have sample code of this library in Jython...